# Validation expression for asp.net regular expression validator

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am using a regular expression validator in my asp.net application. I want to disallow following special characters

```
 \/<>*?';:'',|"
```

What will be validationExpression ?

Please suggest

Comment: post some examples for valid and invalid matches. To disallow the above mentiones characters, you need to put them inside  a negated character class like `[^ \/<>*?;:',|"]`

Comment: everything except these characters is valid , i need alphanumeric values without these special characters

Comment: What's wrong with `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to match the strings which has only alphanumeric characters . If yes, then you could try the below regex.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String regex = "^[^\/<>*?';:'',|\"]*$";
```